# Responsively embed webpage within webpage

Tags: html, responsive-design

I'm building a webapp designed for iDevices to be used in combination with the school website. I'd like to have one section of the webapp have an embedded clip of the school website. Typically I'd use something like this, and be done with it:

```
<object data=http://www.schoolwebsite.org width="600" height="400"> <embed src=http://www.schoolwebsite.org width="600" height="400"> </embed> Error: Embedded data could not be displayed. </object>
```

But that won't responsively, and account for rotation of an iPad or utilization of a different platform.

**How would I edit that code, or create new code to embed an existing webpage within another webpage?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag you are looking for is iframe:

```
<iframe src = "http://www.example.com" />
```

This shows the webpage specified in the page that the code is in.

You can also customize it if you want, specifying the border in the `style`:

```
<iframe src = "http://www.example.com" style = "border: 1px solid" />
```

Replace `1px` with the size of the border.

Also in the style tag, you can specify the `size`, or you can just specify the `width:` and `height` properties.

Comment: This works very well, thank you. However what is the best way to ensure it takes up the full screen on every device? Or at least the areas in which I do not have a navbar.

Comment: @Wizkashifa Well, to make it fullscreen you would specify the width and height as '100%'.

Answer (score 0):

try an iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://www.schoolwebsite.org" style="border:1px black solid;" name="frame" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" align="top" height="400px" width="600px">
</iframe>
```